transform column to JSON ignoring null
I've a table with some columns containing JSON which I need to convert from text to proper JSON.
I can easily do it with = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"my_column", Json.Document}}), however it gives error for missing values (null).
Is there a way to exclude null values from transformation using just a single transformation (i.e. not having an additional step to replace errors to null)?

Depending on the error message, you could use try ... otherwise. BTW, Json.Document does NOT transform text to JSON. Rather it returns the content of a JSON document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-transformcolumns
Table.TransformColumns has a 4th parameter where you can pass in MissingField.UseNull or MissingField.Ignore

I tried to use it like this = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"my_column", Json.Document}}, null, MissingField.UseNull), but it still gives error for null values in the column

just checked the link you posted, it's actually about a missing column, not about a null value within a column

Ah, good catch. I need to read the question more closely. Your solution is the right one.

I've found the solution:
= Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"my_column", each if _ = null then null else Json.Document(_)})
